# Can I use 'j''étais né/née" in French?

Tags: grammaire

Yes, I can!

I was born... can be used in French

"Je ne suis pas un homme d’action, moi, je suis un rêveur. Je n’étais pas né pour être roi, j’étais né pour être poëte. — (Alexandre Dumas, La Reine Margot, 1845, volume I, chapitre III)”

Comment: You can easily check a conjugation table or see the great number of occurrences of [j'étais né](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22j%27%C3%A9tais+n%C3%A9%22) or [j'étais née](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22j%27%C3%A9tais+n%C3%A9e%22) in books.  So what is exactly your question ? It seems you are trying to answer a question and not ask one. Please visit the [Help centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Duplicate with https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23131/quand-j%C3%A9tais-n%C3%A9-or-quand-je-suis-n%C3%A9 ?

Comment: @Graffito If you read the question you refer to and its answers, you'll see that the explanation of Dumas' choice of tense is not given.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This would make an answer on the relevant 
 question linked by Graffitto.

Comment: @LPH  I agree with you there's no duplicate since there's no question asked here. The OP is not  asking for an "explanation of Dumas' choice of tense" but  **answering** their own rhetorical question  with "Yes, I can! I was born... can be used in French".  If the OP wanted to ask a genuine question and not just ask and answer their own question they'll surely clarify the problem.

Comment: @None True, the question is not explicit, but implicitly, there is a question ("I can because Dumas does say it, can't I?").

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no; you can say "j'étais né(e)" if you complete this construction with "*pour*", and then, inextricable confusion with which one has to live, you are not saying "I was born" but "I was destined to".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/naitre)) e)**Être né pour + verbe ou subst.** Être destiné à, avoir des dispositions particulières pour (faire) quelque chose.
>
> - Être né pour agir, diriger, obéir, régner; être né pour le commandement, le trône; être né pour le bonheur, la souffrance; être né pour la peinture.
> - Elle paraissait née pour une vie différente des autres (Martin du G.,Thib., Pénitenc., 1922, p.794).
> - Toute cette humanité inférieure, née pour être esclave, tous ces médiocres, ces gens laids, stupides, mal habillés, pourquoi ont-ils leur part de cette gloire? (Montherl.,Exil, 1929, i, 2, p.28)
> - Beaucoup de courtisanes étaient nées pour être des honnêtes femmes, dit-on; et beaucoup de femmes dites honnêtes pour être courtisanes... Maupass.,Contes et nouv., t.2, Samoris, 1882, p.360.

Then you can say it in those constructions where "naitre" means "to be born" and a tense correspondence is needed, in particular when the act of being born has no incidence on the présent.

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Lorsque_j_%C3%A9tais_illumin%C3%A9/C1dBCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22j%27%C3%A9tais+n%C3%A9%22&pg=PT9&printsec=frontcover)) Ma condition d'homme n'était adaptée que pour le monde dans lequel j'étais né.

- Nous venions d'apprendre qu'il était né en aout.
- Ce jour-là l'employé nous avait dit qu'il est né en aout, pas qu'il est mort en aout; d'autres recherches étaient nécessaire pour déterminer la date de sa mort.
- Elle confirma qu'il était né en octobre.

Nevertheless, there can be cases of erratic usage.

> ([Les imaginaires de Jean-Maurice - Jean-Maurice Bloch · 2017](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_imaginaires_de_Jean_Maurice/oIgvDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22j%27%C3%A9tais+n%C3%A9%22&pg=PA17&printsec=frontcover)) Je me souviens, quand j'étais né, Tout le village a fait la fête, Ils ont bu et tant festoyé Que j'en avais mal à la tête. Je me souviens petit enfant, Fallait obéir aux parents

You can also say it in those constructions where "naitre" means "to be born" and when you use « si » to express either one of two possibilities.

> ([gymglish](https://www.gymglish.com/fr/frantastique-orthographe/grammaire-francaise/si-suivi-du-plus-que-parfait)) La structure *Si + plus-que-parfait → conditionnel passé* permet d’imaginer les conséquences dans le passé d’une action qui n’a pas eu lieu.
>
> - Si j'étais parti à l'heure, je n’aurais pas raté mon train. (sous-entendu : Je suis parti en retard et j’ai raté mon train.)
> - S'il avait fait beau, je serais sorti. (sous-entendu : il n'a pas fait beau et je ne suis pas sorti.)
>
> La structure *Si + plus-que-parfait → conditionnel présent* permet d’imaginer les conséquences dans le présent d’une action qui n’a pas eu lieu.
>
> - S’il n’avait pas plu, je n’aurais pas les cheveux mouillés. (sous-entendu : Il a plu et maintenant j’ai les cheveux mouillés.)

- Si elle était née il y a dix ans elle n'aurait pas vingt ans aujourd'hui.
- Si elle était née un an plus tôt elle aurait ton âge.

The "imparfait" can also be used, but does not appear to be as usual as the "plus-que-parfait".

([Esprit critique - Brice Poreau  2013](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Esprit_critique/048SAgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22si+je+naissais%22&pg=PA127&printsec=frontcover)) Mais, si je naissais dans une famille dont la confession est différente, je n'aurai probablement pas la même religion qui me serait donnée.

([Max Frisch](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Max_Frisch/BL_BGvIg6Y0C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22si+je+naissais%22&pg=PA12&printsec=frontcover)) Quand je cherche par exemple à me représenter ce qui se passerait si je naissais une seconde fois , quand je mets en scène quelque chose qui n'a jamais existé et qui n'existera jamais , mon expérience se révèle plus pure que lorsque…